# ¿Como insertar datos de tipo string en una lista mediante una cola en JAVA?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando lo siguiente

```
List <String> enrolling = new ArrayList<String>();

String name;

enrolling.offer(name);
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es agregar String name a  tu List, basta con lo siguiente enrolling.add(name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `offer(E e)` no se usa con una lista. El método `offer(E e)` significar ofrecer un nuevo elemento a una [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#offer(E)) con una limitación de contenido. La `Queue` puede rechazar la oferta, devolviendo `false`.

Por la razón que `ArrayList` es una lista (sin capacidad limitada) y no una queue, `offer` no esta implementado en listas.

En una `List` se puede usar `add(E e)` para agregar elementos del tipo `E`.

Para usar una cola, usas:

```
// construimos una cola con tamaño 10 elementos max
Queue<String> enrolled = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);

String name = "fulanito";

if (enrolled.offer(name)){
    // el nuevo elemento fue acceptado, trabajemos con eso
} else {
    // la cola estaba llena, así el elemento no fue aceptado.
    // podriamos hacer algo como:
    try{
        enrolled.put(name); // put espera hasta que queda espacio en la cola
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        // todavía no logremos y más encima fuimos interumpido
    }
}
```

Existe una variedad de implementaciones de colas para una multitud de usos, revisa la interfaz `Queue` para referencias a implementaciones concretas.